# Confirm internet data connection before making Firestore Query

Tags: android, google-cloud-firestore

I have the following situation:

The application has the option to like the posts of a user. And also has a Dislike option.

It is working properly when it is on a wifi or mobile network (with online connection).

Problem:

When the network is mobile, it is often connected but has no data transmission and does not work. It is a geographical and operator problem in certain locations in the country.

So it's taking a long time for the Like option to have its effect for either Like or DisLike.

Code:

```
@Override
    public void onLikeSelected(final DocumentSnapshot like) {

        if (checkConnection()){


            final String idCurrentUser = mCurrentUser.getUid();

            Task<QuerySnapshot> query = mDb.collection("Postagens").document(like.getId()).collection("Likes").whereEqualTo("id_userLike", idCurrentUser)
                    .get().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onSuccess(QuerySnapshot documentSnapshots) {

                            if(documentSnapshots.size() == 0) {

                                Map<String, Object> dado_usuario = new HashMap<>();
                                dado_usuario.put("id_userLike", mCurrentUser.getUid());
                                dado_usuario.put("timestamp", FieldValue.serverTimestamp());

                                mDb.collection("Postagens").document(like.getId()).collection("Likes").document(idCurrentUser).set(dado_usuario).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {



                                    }
                                });



                            } else { //utilizando else



                                mDb.collection("Postagens").document(like.getId()).collection("Likes").document(idCurrentUser).delete().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Void>() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void onSuccess(Void aVoid) {



                                    }
                                });

                            }


                        }
                    });



        } else {

            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Not Connection", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

}

 public  boolean checkConnection() {
        boolean conectado;
        ConnectivityManager conectivtyManager = (ConnectivityManager) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        if (conectivtyManager.getActiveNetworkInfo() != null
                && conectivtyManager.getActiveNetworkInfo().isAvailable()
                && conectivtyManager.getActiveNetworkInfo().isConnected()) {
            conectado = true;
        } else {
            conectado = false;
        }
        return conectado;
}
```

How can I do this when the mobile connection is bad or weak

I do not know if it would be the case of handling the data connection or changing the treatment of the Like (onLikeSelected()) option in the Firestore Database.

Thanks!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple approch will be use the following method:

```
public boolean isInternetAvailable() {
    Runtime runtime = Runtime.getRuntime();
    try {
        Process process = runtime.exec("/system/bin/ping -c 1 8.8.8.8");
        int exitValue = process.waitFor();
        return (exitValue == 0);
    } catch (IOException | InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Excuse me. Could you explain what this is going to do? @AlexMamo

Comment: This method verifies for internet connection. Isn't this what you want?

Comment: Yes, exactly that. From what I noticed (on the first answer) how to test, the connection is connected. And, according to your example, test if the device is transmitting. Is that the difference? @AlexMamo

Comment: This method does not test if the device is transmitting if verifies for internet connection. There is a big difference between connected to a network and connected to internet. You can be connected to a network (e.g. wi-fi network) and to not have internet connection. What you need is to test the internet connectivity and not a network connection.

Comment: Okay, thank you so much, I'll do it. Is this the best practice for mobile programming? I wonder why I'm new to mobile application programming. @AlexMamo

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to do this thing one is check at a instance and another is making a broadcast receiver

```
    public static boolean internetAvailable(Context context) {
    ConnectivityManager connectivityManager = (ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    NetworkInfo activeNetworkInfo = null;
    if (connectivityManager != null) {
        activeNetworkInfo = connectivityManager.getActiveNetworkInfo();
    }
    return activeNetworkInfo != null && activeNetworkInfo.isConnected();
}
```

And the other one is

```
public class NetworkChangeReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
public static final String TAG = "NetworkChangeReceiver";
public static ConnectivityReceiverListener connectivityReceiverListener;

public NetworkChangeReceiver() {
    super();
}

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) context
            .getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    NetworkInfo activeNetwork = null;
    if (cm != null) {
        activeNetwork = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
    }
    boolean isConnected = activeNetwork != null
            && activeNetwork.isConnectedOrConnecting();

    if (connectivityReceiverListener != null) {
        connectivityReceiverListener.onNetworkConnectionChanged(isConnected);
    }
}

public interface ConnectivityReceiverListener {
    void onNetworkConnectionChanged(boolean isConnected);
}
```

}

Happy Coding :)

Comment: how could I use it in my current code? @ShivamMathur

Comment: You can't check if you have a working internet connection or not but some people use to ping google and check if response time is greater than 5 sec then the internet is slow. But the approach fails in so many circumstances  so in your code just replace 
**if (checkConnection())** to **if(internetAvailable(context))**

Comment: Excuse me, but I was a bit confused. Are you taking me to test for 5s or just use the method to if(internetAvailable(context)). @ShivamMathur