# Flutter Firestore Set Timeout

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

As far as I know Flutter Firestore operation will keep retry when the internet connectivity is down. Is there a way to set timeout duration so that Firestore throw an error in CatchError when it exceeds the timeout duration?

Answer (score 7):

try this to handle a timeout at app initialization:

```
  Future<FirebaseApp> app;
  void appInit() {
    app.timeout(Duration(seconds: 5), onTimeout: (){
      // handle app timeout here
    });
    app = FirebaseApp.configure(
      name: 'test',
      options: const FirebaseOptions(
        googleAppID: googleAppID,
        gcmSenderID: projectID,
        apiKey: apiKey,
        projectID: projectID,
      ),
    );
  }
```

this will handle a transaction timeout:

```
Firestore.instance.runTransaction((Transaction tx) {
  // handle transaction here
}).timeout(Duration(seconds: 5), onTimeout: () {
  // handle transaction timeout here
});
```

Comment: is there a documentation for `timeout`? i can't find it

Comment: @kirill_igum The `timeout` method is part of the `Future` class in Dart. You can find the doc here https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.10.4/dart-async/Future/timeout.html.

Answer (score 2):

### Firestore Offline mode is enabled by default for Android and IOS!

> Cloud Firestore supports offline data persistence. This feature caches
> a copy of the Cloud Firestore data that your app is actively using, so
> your app can access the data when the device is offline. You can
> write, read, listen to, and query the cached data. When the device
> comes back online, Cloud Firestore synchronizes any local changes made
> by your app to the Cloud Firestore backend.

For that reason, if you are not dealing with [transactions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/transactions#transactions) (atomic operations), then **You don't need to await for Firestore acks**, and you don't need to use timeouts at all!

- Checkout this awesome video:
  https://youtu.be/oDvdAFP6OhQ?t=704
- Firestore documentation:
  https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/enable-offline

### Important note

Whenever users go online again, their actions will take place immediately, so you want to make sure to use actions such as `ArrayUnion` on lists and `Increment` for numeric values.

### Web

Offline mode can be manually enabled for Web.