# Is it possible to set timeout for Firestore write operations (Android)?

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

```
 FirebaseFirestore.getInstance()
.collection(ROOT_COL) .add(data) 
.addOnSuccessListener {  } 
.addOnFailureListener { e ->  };
```

For instance when the user writes the data to a server, the write operation should fail after specified time has passed. I also need a callback when there is a loss of internet connectivity during writing.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/72305006/12695188

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Write operations never time out, and they never fail due to loss of network.

You should not think of Firestore reads and writes as typical input and output operations.  Data written to Firestore is **eventually synchronized**, which will happen whenever it's possible to do do.  Documents written are saved locally until they are able to be synchronized with the server, which could be any time in the future.

(The only exception to this is transaction operations, which require a network to complete.)

If this behavior isn't what you want, then you should probably be using some other database product.

Comment: Hi Doug, thanks for the response. My context is I'm displaying progress bar during write, if there is loss in connectivity and there is no callback the progress bar will never stop. Is there any solution to solve this problem ?

Comment: You can implement your own timeout if you want, in order to change the state of your application, but the write behavior for the document cannot be changed.

Comment: @DougStevenson If I implement my own transaction timeout, how can I cancel the running transaction to make sure it does not complete in the end?