# How to set timeout setting for python-firestore AsyncClient?

Tags: python, google-cloud-firestore, python-asyncio, fastapi, pytest-asyncio

I'm using google.cloud.firestore with Async Client, and I want to add timeout setting for adding documents but I can't somehow...

## Versions

- Python: 3.9.7
- google-cloud-firestore: ">=2.1.0"
- API framework: fastapi:  "^0.70.0"
- pytest: "^6.2.5"
- pytest-asyncio: "^0.16.0"

## Problem

When I run this code `without setting firebase server turning on`:

```py
from firebase_admin import firestore
db_client = firestore.AsyncClient()

async def some_function():
  await asyncio.wait_for(
    db.collection('states')
      .add({'some':'values'})
    ,timeout=10
  )
```

this should cause error `only after when 10 secs` has passed, but actually this causes errorr `immidiately` saying:

```
503 failed to connect to all addresses
```

How can I fix `db.collection('states').add(...)` to wait appropriately?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you confirm if the code "db.collection('states').add(...)" works, without wrapping it around the asyncio timeout settings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you should check if there are any networking settings blocking connections. 503 means the library is unable to make a connection with the backend API. Now coming to Firestore timeout values, there is no way to adjust that. The timeout requests defaults to a system specified value as per [this](https://googleapis.dev/python/firestore/latest/client.html).

Write operations never time out, and they never fail due to loss of network. You should not think of Firestore reads and writes as typical input and output operations. Data written to Firestore is eventually synchronized, which will happen whenever it's possible to do so.

Unlike in Firebase Realtime database where to enable offline persistence, you have to do the following :

```
FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().setPersistenceEnabled(true);
```

In Cloud Firestore, offline persistence is enabled by default. So, there is no need to use: setPersistenceEnabled(true). When you are offline the result will be from the cached copy of the Cloud Firestore data that your app is actively using. To check if the data is from cache or from Firestore servers, you can use the following line of code:

```
String source = querySnapshot.getMetadata().isFromCache() ? "Local Cache" : "Firebase Servers”
```

Documents written in Firestore are saved locally immediately if not executed, until they are able to be synchronized with the server, which could be any time in the future.

- To detect whether it will be able to do so, have a look at this
  [stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50594619/15803365).
- To detect when the document has been written to the server, use a
  SuccessListener. This example from the [Firestore documentation on
  adding documents](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data#add_a_document) shows how:

// Add a new document with a generated id.

```
Map<String, Object> data = new HashMap<>(); 
data.put("name", "Tokyo"); 
data.put("country", "Japan"); 
db.collection("cities") .add(data) .addOnSuccessListener(
new OnSuccessListener<DocumentReference>() { 
@Override public void onSuccess(DocumentReference documentReference) 
{ Log.d(TAG, "DocumentSnapshot written with ID: " + documentReference.getId()); 
} })
 .addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() { 
@Override public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) 
{ Log.w(TAG, "Error adding document", e); 
} });
```

Note : The onSuccess or onFailure will only be called if there is a connection to the server. The only exception to this is transaction operations, which require a network to complete.

However there is a [request](https://github.com/googleapis/python-firestore/issues/25) in the Python client library for Firestore asking for this improvement. Also have a look at this for [reference](https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-dotnet/issues/2471).